# Routing not working as expected in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

`mywebsite.com/it/moto/` should redirect to the home page. Hence i wrote this in routes.php

```
$route['(\w{2})/(auto|moto)/(.*)'] = '$3';
$route['(\w{2})/(auto|moto)'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

which works pretty good. Also, `mywebsite.com/it/moto/mercatino` routes to `Mercatino` controller, which is perfect.

No, i want this `mywebsite.com/it/moto/mercatino/componenti-veicolo/221/molle-originali-r6` to route to this function inside `Mercatino` controller

```
public function prodotto($category, $id, $title){

}
```

hence, i wrote this line in routes.php

```
$route['(mercatino|market){1}/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = "mercatino/prodotto/$2/$3/$4";
```

But i get 404 Error. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this way

```
$route['(.*)/(mercatino|market){1}/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = "mercatino/prodotto/$3/$4/$5"; //rule 1
$route['(\w{2})/(auto|moto)/(.*)'] = '$3'; //rule 2
$route['(\w{2})/(auto|moto)'] = $route['default_controller']; //rule 3
```

By putting the `mercatino` rule before all the other rules and adding `(.*)` before.

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['(mercatino|market){1}/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = "mercatino/prodotto/$2/$3/$4";
```

How many directories are in "mercatino/prodotto/$2/$3/$4" ? By default codeigniter I think doesn't go into directory more than level 2.

What I mean is, when codeigniter look for files it assume that there can be only one more directory inside controller. So, if you have `controllers/d1/file.php` you are fine but if you have `controllers/d1/d2/file.php` it won't work with default behaviour of CI.

To make it work you will probably have to override the `Router class` and `fetch_directory` function or `_validate_request` function may be.

Comment: There are no directories. All the "directories" after `/prodotto/` are passed as parameters to the `prodotto()` function, that's what codeigniter does. So, for example, if you have a url like `/dir1/dir2/dir3/..../dirn/` CI will access the class `Dir1`, call the funcion `dir2` and pass the parameters `/dir3/.../dirn/` to that function

Comment: ok, I got your point. May be you can try removing `{1}`. May be CI do not support that type of regex in route. Not sure exactly.

Comment: I found the solution. Look at my answer